# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory ( in AudioSegment)

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

Script :

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/srv/python/welcome.mp3")
sound.export("/srv/python/test", format="wav")
```

ERROR:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/srv/python/test'
```

path `/srv/python/test` is exits with write permission (777) and `/srv/python/welcome.mp3` is also exits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the `pydub` docstring for the method you're using (my emphasis):

> Export an `AudioSegment` to a ***file*** with given options
>
> `out_f` (string): Path to destination audio ***file***

the parameter is supposed to be a *file.*

You appear to have provided a *directory* as the argument, so you may want to change it to something like:

```
sound.export("/srv/python/test/actual_file_name.wav", format="wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

I Was wrong in

```
sound.export("/srv/python/test", format="wav")
```

line, first param should be file instead of folder location

```
sound.export("/srv/python/test/welcome.wav", format="wav")
```